# Static method for filtering all documents based on property of enum type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, static-methods

I have in my `userSchema` for `role` a `user` and `admin` but I'm not sure how I can create a static method to return all documents based on if the user is an `admin` or `user`.

I did try the following...

```
userSchema.statics.findByRole = function (role) {
  return this.find({ role: role });
};
```

but that didn't work.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a valid email address!'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Password is required!'],
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

userSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function () {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
});

userSchema.statics.findByRole = function (role) {
  return this.find({ role: role });
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: `find` is asynchronous, you probably need to `await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for find, findOneAndUpdate, etc you should use async/await; Because getting connected to the database can be time consuming.

```
userSchema.statics.findByRole = async function (role) {
  await this.find({ role: role })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that based on @Joe comment. But I just realized I wasn't returning anything, and this was my issue! Thanks though for the response.